# Compare a CSV File with Active Directory Users and provide Domain

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory, membership

I have a CSV list that I want to compare with active directory and create a list of all users and the group membership. This is what I have so for but I'm getting an error with the brackets. Can anyone help?

```
$csvEmployees = Import-Csv -Path C:\IT\list.csv
$adUsers = Get-AdUser -LdapFilter '"(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))"' -Properties EmployeeID,GivenName,Surname
$csvEmployeesInAd = $csvEmployees.foreach({
$employee = @{
'EmployeeID' = $_.EmployeeID
'Given Name' = $_.GivenName
'Surname' = $_.GivenName
'InAD' = $_.MemberOf
 }
if ($_.EmployeeID -in $adUsers.employeeId }) {
$employee.InAD = $NotinAD
}
[pscustomobject]$employee })
```

Comment: Remove the `}` right after `$_.EmployeeID -in $adusers.employeeId` in the `if` condition

Comment: in addition to what MathiasR.Jessen pointed out ... if you simply use proper indents and layout as shown in the PoSh style guide, you would be far more likely to catch thins sort of error. [*grin*]

Comment: Did you intend to specify `'Surname' = $_.GivenName`?

Comment: Also, you don't need `(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)`. The command already does that. You can safely specify `Get-AdUser -LdapFilter '(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)'`.